# how can I get a reference without render the component

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I use the react-native-maps from Airbnb. I want to take a snapshot without render the mapView. It's possible. 
My code like this :

```
componentDidMount(){
 const map = <MapView ref={map => this.mapRef = map} />
 const snapshot = this.mapRef.takeSnapshot({
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        region: {
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324
        },
        format: 'png',
        quality: 0.8,
        result: 'file'
    });
    snapshot.then((uri) => {
        console.warn(uri);
    });

}
```

The mapRef is undefined . Why ???

Comment: Ref can only be defined on a mounted/mounting component, so you have to render MapView in your case (you can still hide it to the user if it's why you don't want to render it)

Comment: good i do this i set the map styles with width zero and height zero. Is it a good idea ???

Comment: I think it's ok, maybe what you need could be fetch from an api instead, saves a lot of compute resources.

Comment: i want to show an Image before the user navigates to screen that i show the map

Comment: So if your need is to show an image during the loading time of MapView you can't do it that way, this will take the same time to display the image.

Comment: okay thank for you help !!!